# How can I reduce $\sum_{i=1}^n (i^2-i+1/4)$ to a function of $n$?

Tags: series-expansion

How can I reduce $\sum_{i=1}^n (i^2-i+1/4)$ to a function of $n$?

Comment: I mean $\sum_{i=1}^N(i^2-i+1/4)$

Comment: `Sum[(i^2 - 1 + 1/4), {i, 1, n}]` returns `1/12 (-7 n + 6 n^2 + 4 n^3)`